# difficulty understanding this part of block programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

This is from [apple blocks docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW3) and I am having difficulty understanding this please can any one explain it

> If you don’t explicitly declare the return value of a block
>   expression, it can be automatically inferred from the contents of the
>   block. If the return type is inferred and the parameter list is void,
>   then you can omit the (void) parameter list as well. If or when
>   multiple return statements are present, they must exactly match (using
>   casting if necessary).

Comment: Which of the three sentences above are you having difficulty with ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) **If you don’t explicitly declare the return value of a block expression, it can be automatically inferred from the contents of
    the block**

The block

```
void ^(float aFloat) {
   printf("value is :%f",aFloat);
};
```

can also be written as

```
^(float aFloat) {
   printf("value is :%f",aFloat);
};
```

without saying the return type. The return type is automatically inferred. It is true for blocks that returning non void values.

2) **If the return type is inferred and the parameter list is void, then you can omit the (void) parameter list as well**

This is bit tough to understand and confusing, since documentation specifically saying

> A block that takes no arguments must specify void in the argument
>   list.

I believe this kind of blocks is possible.

```
 ^{
     printf("Hello world");
 }
```

where return value is inferred, and because of that, a void is not needed. I am not sure about this, so would like some clarification.

3) **If or when multiple return statements are present, they must exactly match (using casting if necessary).**

Simply means, a block must return only one type of data. It can't return an int **and** float.

Comment: `^{ printf("Hello world"); }` is also sufficient.

Comment: So then **A block that takes no arguments must specify void in the argument list.** is wrong?

Comment: but this is giving an error     void ^(float aFloat) {
        printf("value is :%f",aFloat);
    };

Comment: and this is giving Expression result unused     ^(float aFloat) {
        printf("value is :%f",aFloat);
    };

Comment: @S.J that's because `printf()` returns an `int`. The compiler is telling you that it has inferred a return value of an int, but you aren't using it. I believe this also applies to the answerer's point 2